# Autofill Input Field Based On Another Input Field OnKeyUp (Dynamic Generated)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hope today I'll find good solution for my case below.

**Case**

Actually, I have dynamic input fields and let say there field A, B and C. So, the purpose is when field A receives OnKeyUp Action then field B and C will autofill based query result from field A value.

**index.php**

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ct = 1;

        // Function Tambah Form
        function new_link()
        {
            ct++;
            var div1 = document.createElement('div');
            div1.id = ct;

            // Link to Delete Form
            var delLink = '<div style="text-align:left"><a id="del" href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';
            div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
            document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
        }
        // Function Delete Form
        function delIt(eleId)
        {
            d = document;

            var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);

            var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');

            parentEle.removeChild(ele);
        }

        function ajaxFunction(str,divId)
        {
            var httpxml;
            try
            {
                // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                // Internet Explorer
                try
                {
                    httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function stateChanged()
            {
                if(httpxml.readyState==4)
                {
                    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
                }
            }
            var url="cek.php";
            url=url+"?txt="+str;
            url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
            httpxml.send(null);
        }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm">
    <a id="new" href="javascript:new_link()">ADD NEW PAYMENT</a>
    <div id="newlink">
    <table width="50%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"
    onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv');" name="username" /></td>
        <td>
        <div id="displayDiv">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="curr"></td><td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none" >
    <div>
    <table width="50%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"
    onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>');" name="username" /></td>
        <td>
        <div id="displayDiv<?php echo $np;?>">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="curr"></td><td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

**cek.php**

```
<?php
    mssql_connect('localhost','sa','');
    mssql_select_db('NCD');

    $in=$_GET['txt'];
    $msg="";
    $t=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM DPaym1 WHERE (JENIS = 1) AND (DPSPAID = 0) AND (CNDPSNO = '$in')");
    while($nt=mssql_fetch_array($t)){
        //$msg = "$nt[CURRID]#$nt[AMOUNT]";
        $curr = "$nt[CURRID]";
        $amount = "$nt[AMOUNT]";
    }
    //echo $msg;
    //echo "$curr&nbsp;$amount";
    ?>
    <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="curr" value="<?php echo $curr?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount?>"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Above code already success for row 1. but when I input value in row 2 (dynamic add new row) the result change field B and C in row 1 not in row 2.

Comment: You have `document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;` so it will always change `<div id="displayDiv">` and never `<div id="displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>">`. You will need to pass the `div` id to your `function ajaxFunction(str)`.

Comment: thanks Mr.Sean for your reply. I think so too.. could you show me how to pass div id to function ajaxFunction(str) ? I'm really appreciate it for your help sir

Comment: **(1)** add it to your function - `function ajaxFunction(str,divId)`, **(2)** change `document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;` to `document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;` (match `divId` in `function ajaxFunction(str,divId)`), **(3)** add it to your function calls - `<input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv');" name="username" />` AND `<input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>');" name="username" />`

Comment: Just realized that `onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>');"` and `<div id="displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>">` would cause `$np` to increment too much, causing them not to line up. Change `<div id="displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>">` to `<div id="displayDiv<?php echo $np;?>">` so it does not increment twice.

Comment: Thanx Mr.Sean. I already update my code above just like your solution. Now, when i'm input value in field A(row 2) field B and C in row 1 not changed. but field B and C in row 2 that supposed changed, just not change (it is supposed change when i input value in field A row 2).. Please correct me sir

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm late read your last comment. It is work now sir. When it is start with one row, it is successfully load. And then i click add new payment to add second row, it is succesfully load. But when i add third row and so on, not field B and C in third row that changed but field B and C in second row (it is supposed change field B and C in third row or fourth row and so on).. I'm sorry to many ask you sir, but please could you correct me again sir? thanks a lot..

Comment: Your function - `function new_link()` just copies your `<div id="newlinktpl">` -> `div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML` so it will just copy `onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value,'displayDiv<?php echo ++$np;?>');"`. So you will need to find a way change the function parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem i dont understand. How to update function new_link() so that every time its clicked, it the number $np will increase too...  hope someone help me to fix this..